# How AdS/CFT solves the non-renormalizability of gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, renormalization, ads-cft

According to AdS/CFT, all gravity calculation in AdS can be mapped to CFT calculations on the boundary. Then what are the loop divergences in AdS gravity be mapped to the CFT side? Or put it differently, how can the non-renomalizability of gravity be viewed/solved on the CFT side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained in several ways. I'll follow an approach summarized in [Shomer 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3555), though it's older than that. In doing so, I'll focus on your titular question rather than the specifics of loop divergence treatment. However, you'll learn a lot of the relevant theory in the above link, which is designed to be pedagogical rather than original.

In $d$-dimensional spacetime, a renormalizable quantum field theory's high-energy limit is a conformal field theory with entropy-energy relation $S\propto E^p$ with $p=1-1/d$. Gravity's entropy-energy relation is of this form with geometry-dependent $p$. in Adding a central mass added to an otherwise Minkowski spacetime, i.e. with $\Lambda=0$, achieves $p=1+1/(d-3)$. If however we add the mass to an otherwise AdS spacetime (i.e. with $\Lambda<0$), we get $p=1-1/(d-1)$. This means the high-energy limit matches a CFT on the boundary of the spacetime manifold.